# Correlation of Rolling Two Dice

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, correlation

If A is a random variable responsible for calculating the sum of two independent rolls of a die, and B is the result of calculating the value of first roll minus the value second roll, is is true that A and B have a $cov(A,B)\neq 0$? In other words, is it true that they are **correlated**?

I've come to the conclusion that they must be correlated because they are **not** independent, that is, the event of **A** can have an impact on event **B**, but I remain stuck due to the fact that **causation does not necessarily imply correlation**.

I know that **independence** $->$ **uncorrelation**, but that the opposite isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

Covariance of independent variables is $0$ but covariance of dependent variables is not necessarily non-zero: it might be $0$ (which is exactly what happens in this case), so your conclusion is untrue.

Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables denoting the number rolled on the two fair die respectively. $X_1,X_2$ are identically distributed. $A=X_1+X_2,B=X_1-X_2$.

$\Bbb E[B]=E[X_1]-E[X_2]=0.\\\Bbb E[AB]=E[X_1^2]-E[X_2^2]=0.$

So the covariance $\Bbb E[AB]-\Bbb E[A]\Bbb E[B]$ is $0$.